# Possible synonyms: "home-screen" and "launcher"

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The tags [home-screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-screen) and [launcher](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/launcher) seem to me to be not usefully distinct. Does the rest of the community see a distinction that I don't?

If not, I propose they be made synonymous.

Answer (score 2):

Coming late to this one, as I was just thinking about the same (and found this by a "search-before-ask"): there are actually 3 tags here going very close together.

- [launcher](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/launcher) seems to be the "parent", having two children
- [home-screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-screen) is part of a launcher (no need to explain which one, as the name is self explaining)
- [app-drawer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/app-drawer) is the second child of our launcher, which you usually get to pressing the "middle button" in the tray.

Though at a first glance it looks like they all could be merged-and-synonymed, we should not do so – as all 3 of them have their dedicated purpose:

- use [app-drawer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/app-drawer) when your question is explicitely and dedicatedly relating to the drawer only, but not to the home-screen component
- same way, just opposite, use the [home-screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-screen) tag when not relating to the app-drawer
- use [launcher](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/launcher) when either referring to both, or not being sure which part you're referring to

However, these tags should be used in XOR manner: I see no need for any combination (except for making them easier to find, maybe ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there. It seems to me that you can talk about one without talking about the other. Can you offer some sample questions where one could be used instead of the other?

I expect that there are probably a bunch of questions that are mis-tagged as one instead of the other, but that doesn't necessarily make them synonyms.

I don't feel strongly either way, though, so I can be convinced.

Comment: I thought that they were two names for the same thing. The UI usually referred to as the "home screen" is managed by the application named "Launcher". No?

Comment: No, the launcher is more than just the home-screen.

Answer (score 0):

They could be merged. But

1. I don't see a benefit atm
2. As I stated before, the don't exactly describe the same

That's why I am against making [home-screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-screen) and [launcher](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/launcher) synonymous.